# is it legal to embed search engines useing cURL & javscript?

Tags: curl, web-scraping, search-engine

I'm thinking of adding a search section On my website, where the visitor can select the search engine (eg: google,bing,duckduckgo), and search for whatever they want.

The visitor can type In the search's Input and a new (pop-up/_blank) window will be open once the search form is submitted.

Is It legal to do that?

Comment: Well most web crawlers do this already, and I've seen this feature on other pages as well, so I guess so.

Comment: How would cURL figure into your plan?   It looks like you would just need an HTML form and possibly a small amount of JavaScript to implement what you want.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller What's the point of your question? , No; I'm thinking of something bigger than that, heaps of features will be In the form!

Comment: If you were using coral to scrape data from other sites that is a possible legal landl mine